# Print a particular section of a page in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, printing

I have a angular 2 application, with lots of components. I got a new requirement where in i need to print a particular section of page. I am doing get element by ID, it prints but styles are not taken as all styles are emulated. All my styles are in Sass so cannot use it directly in print page as it is not compiled. Whats the best way of doing this? I can pass the html also of which section to be printed.